# Thomism: Has any Thomist created an ontology of nouns?

Tags: ontology, aquinas

English philosopher John Wilkins wrote a book outlining a universal language, and included in it was an outline of a noun classification system for classifying all objects (both physical and abstract) in the universe. Has any Thomist attempted something like this?

Someone wrote a good diatribe (that regrettably was deleted) to this question about how St. Thomas Aquinas and Thomism in general are too lofty to consider these kinds of practical problems.

However, to apologize on behalf of St. Thomas Aquinas, this question is all too germane to Thomism, because the question of how to categorize all the nouns in the universe *depends strongly* on metaphysical presuppositions. Unlike verbs, which admit a natural way of classification, nouns require that an external participant *impose* a metaphysical framework on them. And if one wants the noun classification system to last, the metaphysical framework must be strong. And I cannot think of stronger than St. Thomas Aquinas.

Comment: Have you read [St. Thomas's commentary on Aristotle's _Peri Hermeneias_](https://isidore.co/aquinas/PeriHermeneias.htm)? He discusses the _verbum_ and _nomen_. Also, a noun is a particular type of sign; cf. [semiotic Thomism](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4151).

Comment: @Geremia Thank you for your useful information. I just knew that St. Thomas (*ora pro nobis*) had to have touched on this!